Azure Databricks Tutorial MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@171b8379 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
This error is comming up when one tries any course that is related to the azure databricks and it is related to the versioning problem of the scala.
I tried to debug it but it is very hard and at end stucked up with no solution

It is trying the get the major and minor version but fails in some cases.
I kept the code as is and create a new cluster with a different runtime (9.1 LTS, Scala 2.12, Spark 3.1.2) and attached this cluster to the notebook, and it works

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
